# How can i get date from specific week number in SQL/PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried multiple options but i want to know if there is a simpler way to get the dates from a week number.

Ex: 
Week 18

Start date from current week `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW'),'DD.MM.YYYY')`

End date from current ween `TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'IW'),'SUNDAY'),'DD.MM.YYYY')`

This will return `30.04.2018` and `06.05.2018`

But is there a simpler way to get start and end for week 19 for example ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you need to convert from a date to a string.  I would simply use:

```
TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') as date_start
TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') + 6 as date_end
```

You can, of course, use `TO_CHAR()` to get any output format you want.

Comment: Thank you very much @GordonLinoff didn't thought like this but i changed this . you are right .